# Keycloak and quarkus in reverse proxy can't validate token

Tags: nginx, devops, keycloak, quarkus

I have a web application that reads as follows:
in a docker-composite I have:

- my backend under quarkus
- my Bdd postgre
- my keycloak server
- nginx en reverso proxy

when I use quarkus in dev mode it can connect a keycloak in localhost:8080 because docker-compose exposes the keycloak port on my host machine

however when I use the back in production when it is launched by docker-compose it communicates with keycloak on http://keycloak/...

when I claim a token on http://localhost/realm/... (nginx reverse to http://keycloak in my docker-compose network) I get access_token, quarkus in dev mode gets to check it with keycloak on localhost:8080 but not in production mode on http://keycloak, I have a 401 error all the time. in dev it works very well

in prod mode i got :

```
backend             | 2023-07-25 14:58:12,649 DEBUG [io.qua.oid.run.OidcIdentityProvider] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-5) Token verification has failed: JWT (claims->{"exp":1690297195,"iat":1690296895,"jti":"1f35ac14-e9a4-4467-af66-b4decc757626","iss":"http://localhost/realms/web-app-veto","aud":"security-admin-console","sub":"c2610f0f-350d-454a-8708-c1e1352d92b6","typ":"Bearer","azp":"backend-veto","session_state":"5e1787c6-05f5-4cab-9ee1-4194c8763ea3","acr":"1","realm_access":{"roles":["user-veto","active-user","admin-veto"]},"scope":"email profile","sid":"5e1787c6-05f5-4cab-9ee1-4194c8763ea3","email_verified":false,"name":"john kondo","preferred_username":"tom@tom.com","given_name":"john","family_name":"kondo","email":"tom@tom.com"}) rejected due to invalid claims or other invalid content. Additional details: [[12] Issuer (iss) claim value (http://localhost/realms/web-app-veto) doesn't match expected value of http://keycloak:8080/realms/web-app-veto]
```

Has anyone ever had this mistake?